# Implement paintSection for QHeaderView delivered class

Tags: qt, paint, subclassing, qheaderview

```
protected:
  virtual void paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const
  {
    QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
    painter->drawRect(2, 2, 10, 10);
  }
```

Rectangle is not painting. But when paintSection removed it is painting. I need to draw rectangle after call base paintSection.

Answer (score 0):

As it was answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500085/how-to-draw-text-in-derived-from-qheaderview-class) your question, `rect` is an area your should paint at.
If you paint outside of this area your drawings might be erased by painting of other cells.

So use `rect` to draw a rect:

```
painter->drawRect(rect.adjusted(2, 2, -2 , -2));
```

Comment: There seems to be one more problem - from what I saw, whenever you call QHeaderView::paintSection, all the other activities you do to the painter have no effect. E.g. I tried doing fillRect(rect), but it only works if QHeaderView::paintSection call is removed. The same if I draw a diagonal line across he cell. I wonder, what happens in QHeaderView::paint section that overrides everything else you do to the painter...

Comment: Are you doing your drawings after the call of QHeaderView::paintSection?

Comment: I tried both before and after - updated code sample - neither works (I opened a separate question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847252/what-does-qheaderviewpaintsection-do-such-that-all-i-do-to-the-painter-before)

Comment: As @Serge notes, this answer does not solve the problem.  I am hitting the same issue; calling super seems to make the painter non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect the painter across the call to super, which modifies it.  Try this:

```
painter->save();
QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
painter->restore();
```

Also, as Ezee noted, you should be using the rect passed in as the basis for the coordinates you draw at; as suggested in that answer, something like:

```
painter->drawRect(rect.adjusted(2, 2, -2 , -2));
```