# How to draw text in derived from QHeaderView class

Tags: qt, paint, qheaderview

I need to draw text in derived from QHeaderView class. But this code does not work.

```
void HeaderView::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &, int) const
{
    painter->drawText(0, 0, "abcde");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't ignore `QRect` argument. It's a place where the section is located in a header widget.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But drawRect works with 0,0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#paintSection) says:

> Paints the section specified by the given logicalIndex, using the
>   given painter and rect.

That means, you have to use the rect getting as parameter:

```
void HeaderView::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect& rect, int) const
{
    painter->drawText(rect, Qt::AlignCenter, "abcde");
}
```